# iptables POSTROUTING not working in local area

Tags: vpn, iptables, nat

I used command

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o $INTERFACE -p tcp  -j SNAT --to-source $IP
```

to make my server packets visible as $IP.
But the problem is, that **it didn't work inside local area**, so when I'm sending something to address 10.X.X.X, then I'm not visible as $IP, but as older IP.

EDIT:
There are 3 interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 46.X.X.152
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 46.X.X.0
    broadcast 46.X.X.255
    gateway 46.X.X.254

post-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 178.X.X.28 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 178.X.X.28
post-down /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 down
post-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0:1 178.X.X.27 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 178.X.X.27
post-down /sbin/ifconfig eth0:1 down
```

And in my iptables rule $INTERFACE=eth0
and $IP is 178.X.X.28 (form eth0:0)

Comment: You need to provide more details like the number of interfaces, how they are configured and connected, etc..

Comment: Ok, interfaces added in main post.

Comment: Aren't there any other rule masquerading the output packets?

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm sure that not. Outside the local area all are fine, but inside I'm still figuring as old IP address.

Comment: If "my server packets" are coming from the machine that you are talking about, and are not just forwarded by it, then your iptables rule will never apply because local packets go directly into the OUTPUT chain. They never go through the routing process, so POSTROUTING has no effect here.

Comment: "local area"? Hm, what and where is that?

Comment: There is no "routing" of packets within the same network. Routing only happens between different networks. Example1: 192.168.0.1/24 sends a packet to 192.168.0.2/24 -> no routing needed -> your iptables rule doesn't catch the packet --- Example2: 192.168.0.2/24 sends a packet to 10.0.0.1/16 -> routing is necessary -> your iptables rule catches the packet

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to use different source address for  locally generated packet is to use `src` parameter of route.

If you add a route like that:

`ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 46.X.X.254 dev eth0 src 178.X.X.28`

It should use this source address for 10.0.0.0/8 destination.

Comment: Not just the easier way, but (practically) the _only_ way.

Comment: not only, it's possible to use SNAT locally or on other router, configure application to use different address, use mangle+policy routing, depends on details